# Xamarin changing text and color of a label within a listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a label inside a list view which is binded to a datetime property

Instead of showing the datetime value I need to show the hour interval from current time and, if it is less than one hour the text needs to be painted red.

I can accomplish that using a converter but not both rules at the same time. I mean changing color AND text.

Should I use two converters or combine a converter with a trigger or can I do it in one place?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use multiple converter here? I think you can and should. One for the text and one for the text color. Both properties needs a binding to the same view model property.

Comment: I didn't know one could use multiple converters.

Comment: Abnother appproach would be to calculate the hour interval in a getter method of the property and use only one converter for the color?